# Extraction of of Date (mm//dd/year) from a DNA sequence header (Fasta file)

Tags: python, r

I have a large data set of DNA sequences and I want to extract only the date  (mm/dd/year) from the sequence headers. The example formate of my sequences header is given below

```
A/Kilifi/103/2016|A/H3N2|1604282|01/11/2016
A/Kilifi/105/2016|A/H3N2|1604298|03/01/2016
A/Kenya/015/2016|A/H3N2|986922|07/03/2016
```

I have separated the date from the remaining header with |.

How can I extract the date from the header?

Comment: in bash ``cut -d'|' -f4``

Comment: You need to do `grep ">"` first in bash if the input is a FASTA file to ignore the actual sequence

Comment: I used this script and it worked fine.  THankyou for the quick response.

Comment: first, I used this (grep "<") to extract the header of the sequence from the FASTA file including the name and date of the sequence. and then I used (cut -d "|" -f4) to extract the data from the header and I got the date. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.